# cannot resolve methods comparing () and reverseOrder ()

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

This test verifies the correctness of the method of sorting aircraft. Tell me, please, why does comparing () and reverseOrder () write "cannot resolve method"? How can I fix this?

```
@Test
public void testPlanesSortedByMaxLoadCapacity() {
    Airport airport = new Airport(planes);
    airport.sortByMaxLoadCapacity();

    List<? extends Plane> sortedPlanes = airport.getPlanes();
    planes.sort(comparing(Plane::getMaxLoadCapacity, reverseOrder()));
    Assert.assertEquals(planes, sortedPlanes);
}
```

I really need your help

Comment: Do you have the imports at top ?

Comment: Simple: these methods are not declared/imported in the scope where they're called.

Comment: how to import it?)

Comment: Do these methods need an object/interface qualifier ? Also do you know that reversed() method inverts the order previously and reverseOrder() returns the *reverse natural* order ?

Comment: Seems like `import static java.util.Comparator.*;` is missing